# Monotone subsequences of bounded and unbounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

I did some practice proofs of two theorems today, and then read the corresponding solutions. The first theorem said that if $\{x_n\}$ is unbounded then it has a monotone subsequence. To prove this, one simply considers, WLOG, a function $f(n)$ such that $\{x_{f(n)}\}\geq \{x_{f(n-1)}\}$, and we are done.

Now, the second theorem says that if a sequence is bounded, then it will still contain a monotone subsequence; but the proof is much longer in this case. First, it was said that since $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, it has a convergent subsequence $T=\{x_{n_i}\}$. Then it was argued that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N>0$, such that, for $i>N$, $L-\varepsilon<\{x_{n_i}\}<L+\varepsilon$. At least one of the intervals, $(L-\varepsilon]$ or $[L+\varepsilon)$, contains infinitely many elements of $T$. If, WLOG, $(L-\varepsilon)$ has infinitely many elements of $T$, then $H:=T\cap (L-\varepsilon)$ is an infinite subset of the sequence, which converges to $L$. Then what is done is that $\{x_{{n_i}_k}\}$ are constructed as to take $\{x_{n_k}\}$ from $\left(L-\frac{\varepsilon}{k},L\right)\cap H$, such that $a_{i_{k-1}}<a_{i_{k}}$, which seems analogous to the first theorem.

My question is: couldn't we apply the same principle as in the first theorem to the second theorem? What motivates the proof of 2nd theorem to be so much more involved than the 1st one? In the 2nd theorem, a sequence is bounded, but how come this makes such a difference in the proof? There should be some subtle detail which I don't yet see.

Comment: What function would you consider for a bounded sequence?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get your question.

Comment: I mean to say, you said you would prove apply the same principle as in the first theorem. In the first theorem, you used a function $f(n)$ such that $x_{f(n)} > x_{f(n-1)}$. Over here, what function can you use, if you can use any function? Because if you cannot, then obviously there is something about boundedness that is stopping you from using any such function.

Comment: Right, I see. In the bounded case, we just need to pick the elements more carefully, as not to suddenly "get stopped" by the bound. That's the peculiar thing I wasn't seeing at first. Thanks.

Comment: you have converged. You are welcome.